# Masking NetCDF with irregular grid using shape file

Tags: python, mask, geopandas, shapefile

I want to clip and mask a NetCDF file to a shape file. I have read and tried several related posts on how to mask NetCDF with a shape file using python and ArcGIS. However, all of the posts and method I have come across are using commonly seen NetCDF, with latitude and longitude be part of the dimension. the main issue I am running into is that I do not have latitude and longitude in my NetCDF dimension. The NetCDF file is coming from a model run with an irregular grid. Both latitude and longitude are variables with a dimension of "ncol".

```
dimensions:
        ncol = 57816 ;
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (1 currently)
        nbnd = 2 ;
        chars = 8 ;
        lev = 72 ;
        ilev = 73 ;
        cosp_prs = 7 ;
        cosp_tau = 7 ;
        cosp_scol = 10 ;
        cosp_ht = 40 ;
        cosp_sr = 15 ;
        cosp_sza = 5 ;
        cosp_htmisr = 16 ;
        cosp_tau_modis = 7 ;
        cosp_reffice = 6 ;
        cosp_reffliq = 6 ;
variables:
        double lat(ncol) ;
                lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
                lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        double lon(ncol) ;
                lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
                lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        double area(ncol) ;
                area:long_name = "physics grid areas" ;
        double lev(lev) ;`
```

....

In this case, is it possible to mask the data with a shape file? I would like to produce a map like what they have in this post: [post](https://www.guillaumedueymes.com/post/shapefiles_country/)

Below is the code I have, which I believe is relying on having latitude and longitude dimension.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import regionmask as regionmask
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings; warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')
#matplotlib inline

#----------------> Read in the shape file
PATH_TO_SHAPEFILE = './ArcGIS/CA_State.shp'
countries = gpd.read_file(PATH_TO_SHAPEFILE)
print(countries.head())

my_list = list(countries['geometry'])
my_list_unique = set(list(countries['geometry']))
indexes = [my_list.index(x) for x in my_list_unique]
#----------------> Plot the shape of shape file
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
countries.plot(ax=ax)
#plt.show()
#----------------> Select the polygon
countries_mask_poly = regionmask.Regions(np.array(countries.geometry).tolist())
#----------------> Read in NetCDF file
data = 'v2.NARRM.historical_0151.eam.h0.1864-05.nc'
ds = xr.open_dataset(data,decode_times=False)
#ds = ds.assign_coords(lon=(((ds.lon + 180) % 360) - 180)).sortby('lon')
ds = ds.assign_coords(lon=ds.lon).sortby('lon')
ds = ds.assign_coords(lat=ds.lat).sortby('lat')
mask = countries_mask_poly.mask(ds.isel(time=0), lat_name='lat', lon_name='lon')

ds_mask = ds.where(mask==0)
print(ds_mask.lat.values)
```